# Congruence subgroups in arithmetic lattices of $\mathrm{SO}(n,1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, arithmetic-groups

I am currently reading the paper *Deformation Spaces Associated to Hyperbolic Manifolds* by Johnson and Millson, Section 7, and the highlighted bit below has been giving me difficulty:

[image]

Specifically, how do we define this ideal $\frak{a}$ that allows us to get this group $\Gamma=\Gamma(\frak{a})$? I have tried following up the reference to *[Geometric construction of cohomology for arithmetic groups](http://www-old.ias.ac.in/j_archive/mathsci/90/2/103-123/viewpage.html)* by Millson and Raghunathan, but unfortunately despite my best efforts I have really struggled to follow the latter paper and extract anything useful, since I am not only new to hyperbolic geometry, but also completely unfamiliar with number theory.

If someone could concretely describe how to define such an ideal and the group $\Gamma$, I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reference to Millson-Raghunathan may be a little misleading. All that is needed is that if $\Gamma \subset G(\mathbb Z)$ is an arithmetic group in a linear algebraic group $G$ defined over $\mathbb Q$, then  there exists an ideal $m\mathbb Z$ of $\mathbb Z$ such that the group $\Gamma (m)$ of matrices in $\Gamma$ congruent to identity modulo $m$, is ${\bf torsion-free}$.

In your notation, the group $\Phi$ is an arithmetic subgroup of $SO(Q)$ but defined over a number field $K$. By a standard restriction of scalars argument, you may think of $\Phi=SO(Q)(O_K)$ as commensurable to $G(\mathbb Z)$, where $G=R_{K/\mathbb Q}(SO(Q))$ and  where $R$ denotes the restriction of scalars. You may choose the ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $O_K$ to be generated by a rational integer $m$ as in the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

I want to extend the answer of Venkataramana a bit in order clarify how 
you can choose a suitable ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$.

Here is an abstract version of Minkowski's classical theorem.
*Let $G$ be an affine group scheme of finite type over the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ of some algebraic number field.
If $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq \mathcal{O}$ is an ideal such that for every 
prime number $p$ we have $ p\mathcal{O} \not\subset\mathfrak{a}^{(p-1)}$,
then the principal congruence subgroup 
$$ \Gamma(\mathfrak{a}) = \ker\bigl( G(\mathcal{O}) \to G(\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{a}) \bigr)$$ is torsion-free* (cf. III.2.3 in this [thesis](http://othes.univie.ac.at/24144/)).

In particular, here is a concrete example: The ideal
$\mathfrak{a} = m \mathcal{O}$ for any integer $m \geq 3$ always yields a torsion-free principal congruence subgroup.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer! I just want to check: is $\mathfrak{a}^{(p-1)}$ the [power of the ideal](https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Power_of_an_ideal)? Just asking because in Lie algebra theory they often use $\mathfrak{g}^n$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{(n)}$ to mean different things.

Comment: @ಠ_ಠ Yes, $\mathfrak{a}^{(p-1)}$ denotes the $(p-1)$-th power of the ideal. In particular, if some prime number $p \geq 3$ divides $\mathfrak{a}$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq p\mathcal{O}$), then the condition is immediately satisfied since $\mathfrak{a}^{(p-1)} \subsetneq \mathfrak{a}$.